# Laravel 5: How can I add seeder class to autoload?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

I follow the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#database-seeding

I placed `UserTableSeeder` file near `DatabaseSeeder`. In `resources/database/seeds/` folder.
These files are without namespaces (only classes in `app/` are namespaced).

Of course there is an exception: `exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class UserTableSeeder does not exist'`

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: You say you created `UserTableSeeder` but the error says it couldn't find `LanguageTableSeeder`

Comment: I did it with autoloader classmap with `resources/database/seeds` but it seems to be a very ugly solution.

Answer (score 16):

The default Laravel 5 project has a classmap defined in its `composer.json`:

```
{
    // ...
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        // ...
    }
}
```

Run `composer dump` every time you add or remove a class on your `database` directory to update the Composer autoloader

---

Reference: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/develop/composer.json

Comment: Actually, you haven't run composer dump every time you add/remove a class.

Comment: Their docs says you do: "If you need to update the autoloader because of new classes in a classmap package for example, you can use "dump-autoload" to do that without having to go through an install or update." https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Making new seeders in the database directory needs to be dumped or you can manually namespace the DB reflection on every new Seeder file

Answer (score 0):

You should use `composer dump-autoload` command. From the docs:

> Once you have written your seeder, you may need to regenerate Composer's autoloader using the dump-autoload command:
>
> `composer dump-autoload`

Reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding#running-seeders).