# Class tableseeder does not exist (although it really exists) :S

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I get this error when trying to migrate plus seeding my database using laravel 5.4

> [ReflectionException]   Class PostTagTableSeeder does not exist

In fact the file really exist with correct class name

**seeds/PostTagTableSeeder.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Tag;
use App\Post;

class PostTagTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();
        //DB::table('post_tag')->delete();

        $tag1       = Tag::find(1);
        $tag2       = Tag::find(2);
        $tag3       = Tag::find(3);
        $tag4       = Tag::find(4);
        $post1      = Post::find(1);
        $post2      = Post::find(2);
        $post3      = Post::find(3);
        $post4      = Post::find(4);
        $post5      = Post::find(5);
        $post6      = Post::find(6);
        $post7      = Post::find(7);
        $post8      = Post::find(8);
        $post9      = Post::find(9);
        $post10     = Post::find(10);
        $post11     = Post::find(11);
        $post12     = Post::find(12);
        $post13     = Post::find(13);
        $post14     = Post::find(14);
        $post15     = Post::find(15);

        $post1->tags()->attach([$tag1->id,$tag2->id,$tag3->id]);
        $post2->tags()->attach([$tag2->id,$tag4->id]);
        $post3->tags()->attach([$tag2->id,$tag3->id,$tag4->id]);
        $post4->tags()->attach([$tag4->id]);
        $post5->tags()->attach([$tag2->id]);
        $post6->tags()->attach([$tag2->id]);
        $post7->tags()->attach([$tag2->id]);
        $post8->tags()->attach([$tag1->id,$tag4->id]);
        $post9->tags()->attach([$tag1->id,$tag4->id]);
        $post10->tags()->attach([$tag3->id]);
        $post11->tags()->attach([$tag1->id]);
        $post12->tags()->attach([$tag1->id]);
        $post13->tags()->attach([$tag3->id]);
        $post14->tags()->attach([$tag1->id,$tag2->id,$tag4->id]);
        $post15->tags()->attach([$tag1->id,$tag2->id,$tag4->id]);
    }
}
```

**seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(AdminsTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(PostsTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(CategoriesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(CategoryPostTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(TagsTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(PostTagTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(CommentsTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

I have been struggling to fix this issue but yet i still get the same error[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to add column but migration class is not found even It exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662058/want-to-add-column-but-migration-class-is-not-found-even-it-exists)

Comment: Have you tried running just this seeder class?

Comment: try composer dump-autoload -o

Comment: `php composer.phar dump-autoload` will do the trick

Answer (score 49):

Had the same issue and running

```
composer dump-autoload
```

as suggested above by Vape and Oliver fixed the issue. Then re-run the migrations

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

or the seeder

```
php artisan db:seed
```

and it'll run like a charm.

Comment: composer dump-autoload worked for me thank you so much !

Comment: why do I have to always use it when I make a new seeder??

Comment: The seeder files are in the database directory and are not namespaced.  There is more info in the discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426139/laravel-5-how-can-i-add-seeder-class-to-autoload

Answer (score 17):

For some, due to your file structure or composer set-up, all you need to run is:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

or

```
composer.phar dump-autoload
```

Then, retry the seeder script.

Answer (score 1):

When you have written your seeder, you may need to regenerate Composer's autoloader using the dump-autoload command: [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/seeding#running-seeders)

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Now you may use the db:seed Artisan command to seed your database.

Answer (score 1):

If you have migrated to Laravel 8, you will need to namespace your seeder classes as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    
    public function run()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Then, you have to import the seeder classes with the correct namespace.

Then, in your `composer.json` file, remove `classmap` block from the autoload section and add the new namespaced class directory mappings:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
```

Then, run `composer dump`

Finally, the `database/seeds` directory should be renamed to `database/seeders` (if you have not yet renamed it)

This breaking change is documented here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#seeder-factory-namespaces

Comment: My migrations were from a previous version and ported into Laravel 8. I updated the namespace and added `use DB;` then ran `composer dump-autoload` to update my autoload.